# How to extract the first appearance of whole numbers from a list with incremental float values?

Tags: python-3.x

What is the most efficient way to loop through the list and find the first appearance of whole numbers and save those elements in a new list? For this example, I am storing the first 3 numbers, they should be 1.4, 2.1 and 3.

```
import math

list = [.3, .8, 1.4, 1.9, 2.1, 2.7, 3, 3.2, 3.8]

new_list = [0, 0, 0]

for i in list:
    if math.floor(i) == 1:
        print("one:", i)
        if new_list[0] == 0:
            new_list[0] = i

    if i >= 2 and i < 3:
        print("two:", i)
        if new_list[1] == 0:
            new_list[1] = i

    if i >= 3:
        print("three:", i)
        new_list[2] = i
        break

print("\n", new_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain it is the most efficient, but a list comprehension with numpy works well:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([.3, .8, 1.4, 1.9, 2.1, 2.7, 3, 3.2, 3.8])
print([arr[np.where((arr - x) >= 0)][0] for x in np.unique(np.floor(arr[arr >= 1]))])
```

Outputs [1.4, 2.1, 3.0]

Basically, I create a list of unique floored values of your array when above 1:

> np.unique(np.floor(arr[arr >= 1]))

And then loops through it, selecting the first element of the input array where the difference with floored value is the closest to 0.

Answer (score 0):

using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([.3, .8, 1.4, 1.9, 2.1, 2.7, 3, 3.2, 3.8])

(a := arr[arr>=1])[np.unique(a.astype(int),return_index=True)[1]]
array([1.4, 2.1, 3. ])
```